# Failed to save Django formset with queryset

Tags: python, django

i have faced the problem in django formset, i want to update formset using function view, when this line `formset = MyFormset(request.GET or None, instance=form_main, queryset=queryset)` included cant save but if i remove `instance=form_main, queryset=queryset)` it does not populate data but i can add manually and save it. I want this formset to polulate from database and to save it back to database

view.py

```
form_main = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk = pk)
queryset = MyFormset.objects.order_by('item')
  
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = MainForm(request.GET or None, instance=form_lpo)
    formset = MyFormsetForm(request.GET or None, instance=form_main, queryset=queryset)
        
        
elif request.method == 'POST':
    formset = Grn_LineItemFormset(request.POST)
    form = MainForm(request.POST)
        
        
    if form.is_valid():
       newmodel= NewModel.objects.create(................)

    if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                (...........)
```

Comment: Please verify and fix your indentation. The current code sample is invalid, and there may be other indentation mistakes that could change the meaning of the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Only indentation can defines the scope of code in `python`. In your code snippet `if-else` indentation level is not correct for checking GET/POST method.

Fix your indentation level in `if-else` statement in `views.py` file.

```
form_main = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk = pk)
queryset = MyFormset.objects.order_by('item')

if request.method == 'GET':
    form = MainForm(request.GET or None, instance=form_lpo)
    formset = MyFormsetForm(request.GET or None, instance=form_main, queryset=queryset)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    formset = Grn_LineItemFormset(request.POST)
    form = MainForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
    newmodel= NewModel.objects.create(................)
```